# Multiple voltage output power supply

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

I want to power a Raspberry Pi and a set of speakers from one power supply. I thought about uncasing the existing power supplies and connecting them to a power connector but that seemed a bit dangerous? I then found a HDD power supply that already provides 5 and 12v.

(http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/HDD-POWER-SUPPLY-AC-12V-5V-2A-FOR-HARD-DRIVE-MOLEX-EU-/320705061192?pt=UK_Computing_Drive_Cables_Adapters&hash=item4aab82e148)

I guess this is a normal female molex connector that I could then plug to a male connector and then connect to the cable with the connectors for the devices on? A bit like the (rough) diagram below?

[image]

Also the power supply puts out the voltage at 2A but I need it to be at 1500mA and 500mA for each device. Any suggestions how to do that here? Its been a long time since my high school science so please forgive the "basicness" of my question.

Thank You!

Comment: You don't need to worry about the power supply current rating, as long it is at least as much as the load requires.  Each load will only draw the current it requires.

Comment: please see Olin's great answer: [link](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 1):

If you have alook at the adapter pic as below;
 [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgJmS.jpg]
It says 12V@2A and 5V@ 2A . Which meets your requirement. It is not that it will force 2A through your circuit. But it is that it can provide upto 2A and you need to stay within it.